# Magento2.2 language switching not working on catalog pages

Tags: magento2, language, magento2.2, stores

I have magento2.2 fresh installation. I **enabled two languages** I can switch the **language/store** view on the homepage. also on default pages like create an account, forgot password etc.

But when I am on **catalog pages** (product,category etc) when I **click on the language switcher** the page is refreshed but neither the URL changes nor the site language.

Comment: I have the same issue , found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

In order to update the language on your catalog pages, from the admin side, you have to update the attribute values of your categories and products depending on the corresponding storeview.

For example, to change the language-attribute values of the category named **Bags**, go to `Admin=>Catalog=>Catagories`,  click on the category named **Bags** and then change the **Store View** to your required storeview from the available store views list and provide appropriate values for your category attributes.

Clear cache and check your front-end category page. Same way ,make the changes for your products also.

Comment: Hi I already did this, If I change the storeview name in url then the same category or product is displayed correctly in that language, Only from the language switcher it is not working.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.